# Why are Git commits listed as being created by vagrant?

Tags: git, vagrant

I am currently using vagrant for a personal project. When I commit from my Mac, which I do not need vagrant for, the commits are listed as coming from my Github username. When I am using windows and therefore working out of vagrant, the commits are listed as coming from "vagrant". I understand this is not a big deal, but I like seeing the green boxes appear on Github when I commit, and I like seeing the metrics behind my commits. This is making the repo appear as if there are two users committing, when its actually only me.

Running git config --global user.name and git config --global user.email correctly outputs my desired username and email for git. I don't understand why the commits are being listed as "vagrant".

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* like the environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` and `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` can be used, set them with a client config and accept them with the vagrant machine
(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/5fWmRCuIcJA).

Also, if you can use vagrant to log in as a different user (`config.ssh.username`, `config.ssh.password`), git might accept that instead of "vagrant".